# Probability of event in normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable that is normally distributed and $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be (independet) copies of $X$, then we can estimate this probability by using a simple Monte-Carlo estimator: $p := P (X \ge 5) =E(\xi_{X\ge5}) \approx \frac{1}{100000} \sum_{i=1}^{100000} \xi_{X_i \ge 5}.$

But the problem is $P(X \ge 5)$ is a comparably rare event. So I am supposed to find a way to estimate $P(X \ge 5)$ by using a new measure $dP_s = e^{s S_n - n \gamma(s)} dP,$ where $S_n= X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and $\gamma(s) = \frac{s^2}{2}.$  Of course, $dP = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \exp\left(-\frac{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{2} \right) dx$ is the respective normal distribution

$s:=\gamma^*(5)= \frac{25}{2},$ where $\gamma^*$ is the Legendre-Fenchel transform of $\gamma$. (So you can regard $s$ as being fixed).

Does anybody know how the new estimator could look like( it is supposed to be the same estimator, but should somehow use this new measure)? I don't know how to transform this old event into this new frame with the new measure. Does anybody know this?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $P(X_1 \geq 5) = e^{\gamma(s)} E_{P_s}[e^{-sX_1}\mathbf{1}_{X_1 \geq 5}]$ and this latter expectation can be estimated by the Monte-Carlo method (the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are still independent):
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-sX_k}\mathbf{1}_{\{X_k \geq 5\}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{P_s-a.s.} E_{P_s}[e^{-sX}\mathbf{1}_{X \geq 5}].
$$
Finally, you need to simulate the random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ under the measure $P_s$ but this is easy enough since they still have a normal distribution.

By the way, I think that you should take $s=5$ so that $E_{P_s}[X_1]=\gamma'(s)=5$.

Using some simple facts about normal distributions, you should be able to derive a somewhat better estimator:
$$
\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{25}{2}}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-5|X_k|} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{P-a.s.} P(X \geq 5)
$$
With $n=100000$, I obtain $P(X \geq 5) \approx 2.86\,10^{-7}$.

Comment: sorry what does it mean to simulate a random variable under a particular measure. I mean if I simulate $X_i$ I would take a random number that is normally distributed and if this number was greater than 5, I would add $e^{-s \text{random number}}$ and otherwise zero to the sum. What changes now if I simulate $X_i$ under $P_s$? Does this mean that this is $P_S(X_i \ge 5) = e^{s S_i - i \gamma(s)} P(X_i \ge 5)$?

Comment: If $X_1$ is distribution as $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ under $P$, then its distribution under $P_s$ becomes $\mathcal{N}(s,1)$. So you should simulate normal random variables with mean $s = 5$. Alternatively, see the edited part of my answer.